# How can I create a subprocess on Windows that sleeps for a second?

Tags: windows

I'm trying what I thought would be "hello world" to learn the analog of fork/exec on Windows: create a subprocess that sleeps for one second and then exits. GNU coreutils have a nice sleep tool in `/bin`. There seems to be no analog on Windows. What is a simple tool I can invoke as a subprocess on Windows?

Comment: what language are you using? if you are on .net based language, you can use [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't want to sleep the parent process. I want to invoke a subprocess, through the CreateProcess API. That is the goal here: play with and learn the Windows process API. I need small tools to invoke. Ideally: I don't have to write them too, they do nothing significant, they start quickly, they take some arguments, I can configure how long they execute. sleep and bash are great examples on Linux. What is there on Windows? I installed the Linux Subsytem on Windows, but trying to invoke bash just hangs.

Comment: as far as i am aware, windows dont have that feature and you will need to code on by hand.

Comment: Read [multithreading](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-basics) and [multitasking](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/ProcThread/when-to-use-multitasking)

Comment: @eryksun Can you convert your comment to answer? Because that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait via `timeout.exe /t 1 /nobreak`. It displays a countdown in the console. If this is a problem, you can use the creation flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to force it to allocate a new console that has no window. The `/nobreak` option can be omitted in this case, since there's no window for a user to press enter to bypass the countdown.